# Make code run in parallel instead of awaiting every single data handler

Tags: c#, .net, task, parallels

This is the websocket received message event handler. However these subscriptions are awaited and they are currently not running in parallel, so there is that process time prompt message. The idea is to make these data handlers run in parallel, which means `Task.WhenAll` should be used. The data handler is of type `Func<T, ValueTask>`, so it makes sense to be executed in parallel, so that if one of the data handlers contains `await Task.Delay(5000)`, it shouldn't block the others.

```cs
private async ValueTask OnDataReceived(DataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    var timestamp = DateTimeOffset.Now;

    var messageEvent = new MessageEvent(e.Message, timestamp);

    foreach (var subscription in _subscriptions
                    .GetAll()
                    .Where(subscription => MessageMatchesHandler(messageEvent.Data, subscription.Request)))
    {
        var userProcessTime = await MeasureUserProcessTime(async () => await subscription.DataHandler(messageEvent));

        if (userProcessTime.TotalMilliseconds > 500)
        {
            _logger.LogTrace("Detected slow data handler ({UserProcessTimeMs} ms user code), consider offloading data handling to another thread. Data from this socket may arrive late or not at all if message processing is continuously slow.",
                userProcessTime.TotalMilliseconds);
        }
    }
}
```

What about the version below?

```cs
private async ValueTask OnDataReceived(DataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    var timestamp = DateTimeOffset.Now;

    var messageEvent = new MessageEvent(e.Message, timestamp);

    var handlers = _subscriptions
        .GetAll()
        .Where(subscription => MessageMatchesHandler(messageEvent.Data, subscription.Request))
        .Select(subscription => subscription.DataHandler(messageEvent).AsTask());

    _ = Task.WhenAll(handlers);
}
```

or

```cs
private async ValueTask OnDataReceived(DataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    var timestamp = DateTimeOffset.Now;

    var messageEvent = new MessageEvent(e.Message, timestamp);

    var handlers = _subscriptions
        .GetAll()
        .Where(subscription => MessageMatchesHandler(messageEvent.Data, subscription.Request))
        .Select(subscription => Task.Run(() => subscription.DataHandler(messageEvent)));

    await Task.WhenAll(handlers);
}
```

Comment: This cannot be answered without looking at - at least - what `MessageMatchesHandler()` and `DataHandler()` do.

Comment: @TanveerBadar, `MessageMatchesHandler` is boolean and more or less matches request id with response id. Ignore it. You can assume it's always true. About DataHandler, here is where I took it from: https://github.com/Hulkstance/func-data-handler/blob/main/src/DataHandler.Core/BaseWebSocketClient.cs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The version with `await Task.WhenAll` is fine. I assume you still want to keep `MeasureUserProcessTime`, though, since that will give you useful warnings for long handlers.

Comment: Thanks! Should I wrap the Task.Run with the measured process time? Not so sure how to measure it correctly in this case

Comment: Putting the measure inside the `Task.Run` would be slightly more correct, but I would say either is fine.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/nJNL3m6U I did this but `Task.Delay` in the 2nd data handler is blocking the 3rd one.

Comment: The pastebin code is running the handlers concurrently. If one handler is blocking on another, that is likely because there's some coordination within the handlers themselves.

Comment: You can run this example https://github.com/Hulkstance/func-data-handler/blob/main/tests/DataHandler.Samples.Console/Program.cs and modify just https://github.com/Hulkstance/func-data-handler/blob/main/src/DataHandler.Core/BaseWebSocketClient.cs#L107-L134

Comment: https://pastebin.com/Ci5fT6cd this seems to have worked. `Task.Run` is kinda needed because `await dataHandler(new DataEvent<T>(result.Entity.Data, messageEvent.ReceiveTimestamp));` is awaited in `SubscribeAsync` and there is a Task.Delay in the `Func<DataEvent<T>,ValueTask>` in Program.cs

Answer (score 0):

I suppose somewhere you have some synchronization mechanism with SemaphoreSlim entities, but anyway... why don't you simply fire and forget if you don't do anything with the results of your tasks?

```
private  void OnDataReceived(DataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e is null)
        {
            _logger.Warning("!!!!!!!");
            return;
        }
        var timestamp = DateTimeOffset.Now;

        var messageEvent = new MessageEvent(e.Message, timestamp);

        foreach (var subscription in _subscriptions
              .GetAll()
              .Where(subscription => MessageMatchesHandler(messageEvent.Data, subscription.Request)))
        {
            Task.Run(() =>
            {
                try
                {
                    var handlers = _subscriptions
                        .GetAll()
                        .Where(subscription => MessageMatchesHandler(messageEvent.Data, subscription.Request))
                        .Select(subscription => subscription.DataHandler(messageEvent).AsTask());
                    var userProcessTime = await MeasureUserProcessTime(async () => await subscription.DataHandler(messageEvent));

                    if (userProcessTime.TotalMilliseconds > 500)
                    {
                        _logger.LogTrace("Detected slow data handler ({UserProcessTimeMs} ms user code), consider offloading data handling to another thread. Data from this socket may arrive late or not at all if message processing is continuously slow.",
                            userProcessTime.TotalMilliseconds);
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                }
            });
        }             
    }
```

Comment: There isn't SemaphoreSlim if u check the link with the code in the comments above (it's also testable).  That handler is of type `Func<MessageEvent,ValueTask>`, which means it is returning a value. You can run it without making any changes and you can see that the second handler is slowing down everything downstream.